# Convert large String of number to integer in java

Tags: java, javafx

I want to convert large String to Integer but happen NumberForamtExceptin as :

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "56465478484"
```

I try all methods that convert String to number like

```
Integer.parseInt().
Integer.valueOf().
and others
```

when I enter a large number more than 9 the Exception occurs..
any help appreciate

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does this have to do with [tag:j] or [tag:javafx]?

Comment: 2,147,483,647 is Integer.MAX_VALUE. It has 10 digits. But when you enter a number more than 10 digits, it is probably bigger. Try inputting 1000000000 (1 x 10^9).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `BigInteger` instead of `int` for your variables.

`Integer` (`int`) variables range is `-2,147,483,648 .. 2,147,483,647`. So anything numerically larger than those, will result in an error in Java.

```
String s0 = "23983838282828388382";
String s1 = "11929291882383717771";
BigInteger bi0 = new BigInteger(s0);
BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(s1);
// you can do math operations on BigIntegers
BigInteger biSum = bi0.sum(bi1); // it's not pretty, but it works
```

Comment: don't you think there is probably a duplicate for such trivial issue?